# Charged pendulum oscillations

Tags: electromagnetism

Recently, a question was asked in our school, regarding the calculation of the time period of a charged pendulum bob suspended in an electric field with the help of an insulating thread(gravity also present). Although it is simple at the high school level, shouldn't there be EM radiation from the swinging pendulum ? If that is so, the time period should increase over time as well. Can we obtain an expression as to how the time period changes over time?

Comment: EM radiation (given by Lamor Formula) will be negligible for accelerations on the  order of g.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula.)  You can derive an expression  for change in period if you want one - or are you expecting somebody else to do it for you?

Comment: Oh no! .... I would've just liked a hint as to how to proceed mathematically....thanks!

Comment: Draw a free body diagram.  Identify the forces.  Apply F=ma.  Write down the equation of motion, the same as you would for the gravitational pendulum.  With the energy-radiation term it will be like a damped harmonic oscillator.  Comparing with the eqn for DHO you can identify the frequency and decay factor.... Why do you think that the period should increase over time?